# SSRS output side by side

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Looking at how to output a certain way.

Right now this is how SSRS outputs my table:

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB5qE.png)

This is how I would like the table to output:

[My expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JNhR.png)

Comment: Will this report be only printing just the two records or will it be printing more records than the two in your example?

Comment: More records than just two

Answer (score 0):

Use Matrix and define the field with ID (777xxx) in the column group

Comment: How do I only restrict up to two on the same page?

Comment: When I set page break for group it does not do it.

Comment: If you need to limit 2 on each page, you need to add a field something like page_num in your query. For the IDs on the same page, they will have the same value for the page_num. Then in the matrix, add the page_num as the parent column group to the ID, and set page break to page_num group

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your Data into my local Report. First step you data is something like below

```
      ID    CITY         PRIMARYORELEMENTARY 
    7777888 Houston,TX  Elementary
    7777889 Houston,TX  Elementary
    7777890 Mumbai,IN   Primary
    7777891 Delhi,IN    Elementary
```

Now you could so in your SSRS something like below.

1. Insert and then matrix

[image]

2. After you have matrix then you see matrix as below. Then in column select ID

[image]

3. Now select Rows and then add row inside group below

[image]

4. Now select Primary Element and City in two rows 1 after another.
   [image]

Once you follow all the steps, below is how you will get your Report

[image]